# C# Check if system is 64bit from Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I created a windows service that wants to check if the system is 64bit or 32bit and after checking this downloads the appropriate files from my server .But the code i have now is not working.

I am using.

```
int system = IntPtr.Size;
if (system == 4)
{
    //the system is 32 bit
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.myserver.com/updates/dll/bin.dll", "C:\bin.dll");    
}
if (system == 8)
{
    //the system is 64bit
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.myserver.com/updates/dll/64/bin.dll", "C:\bin.dll");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Does `IntPtr.Size` always return `4`?

Comment: @GáborBakos  the file never downloaded....

Comment: DownloadFile is [expecting a filename as the second parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and not a path.

Comment: @stuartd i have added the path but still not working

Comment: Does the service have enough permissions to write to the root of the C drive?

Comment: @stuartd i really don't know ...maybe not...

Comment: It will need admin permissions to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking pointer size you can just use [System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to check if your operation system version is x64.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using IntPtr.Size use the built in function instead. MSDN says https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem(VS.100).aspx 
It can be called through Environment